# Does DLL keep state between JNI calls?

Tags: java, c++, visual-c++, java-native-interface, c++-cli

I have a C++/CLI code that I need to link with Java via JNI.

That code was not designed to be a dll library and so I met problem:

1. I need to load parameters from file first (C++ code does it)
2. Then initialize connect to hardware using parameters loaded at step 1
3. Then connect to hardware and perform actions

The question is:

1) if I make 3 native calls to my .dll will DLL keep state(loaded parameters)?

Comment: Depends on the c++ code. Given the current state of the question, this is a black box for us.

Comment: The code is huge and WinForms. The logic is spreaded over the code, and I'm very unfamiliar to C++ to make a snippet that shows what's happening there.

Comment: Well, I can only give you some general hints here: If the c++ code accesses global (and/or static) variables, either directly or via singleton, they state is preserved until the DLL is unloaded. If thats the case, the vars become destroyed resulting in appropiate cleanup taking place (automatic storage duration / RAII). I think your best option is simply to try it and see what happens.